# What should I do if I received a mail from company about offer letter by post but a week passed out I haven't received yet?

Tags: job-offer, employer-relations

The company has written in mail that I will be receiving their offer letter within 2-3 days by post but no letter received yet and my onboarding is scheduled on 25 August.

Answer (score 1):

Pick up the phone and ask them what's happening.

It is entirely appropriate to directly call the HR department, preferably whomever you have previously been in contact with there. This is part of their job.

Comment: As it is a big it company I don't think it is right to direct call the hr

Comment: It is entirely appropriate to directly call the HR department, preferably whomever you have previously been in contact with there. Thus is part of their job.

Comment: without an explanation, this answer may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion. For example, if someone posts a claim like _"Don't pick up the phone and avoid asking them what's happening._, how would this answer help reader to pick of two opposing opinions? Consider [edit]ing it into a better shape, to meet [answer] guidelines

Comment: Big company or no, the HR department *is* responsible for sending out offer letters and other employment-related documents. (The hiring manager is not.) An alternative is to call the hiring manager and to ask that *s/he* call HR. You need that letter in your hand if "onboarding" is a week hence. (They might decide not to trust the mail and to have the letter ready. Maybe they can e-mail you a PDF ...)